# javascript getting a faulty result using a regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

In my web page, I have:

```
var res = number.match(/[0-9\+\-\(\)\s]+/g);  
alert(res);
```

As you can see, I want to get only numbers, the characters +, -, (, ) and the space(\s)

When I tried `number = '98+66-97fffg9'`, the expected result is: `98+66-979`
but I get `98+66-97,9`

the comma is an odd character here! How can eliminate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its probably because you get two groups that satisfied your expression.

**In other words:** `match` mechanism stops aggregating group when it finds first unwanted character -`f`. Then it skips matching until next proper group that, in this case, contains only one number - `9`. This two groups are separated by comma.

Try this:

```js
var number = '98+66-97fffg9';
var res = number.match(/[0-9\+\-\(\)\s]+/g);  
// res is an array! You have to join elements!
var joined = res.join('');
alert(joined);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're getting this because your regex matched two results in the number string, not one. Try printing `res`, you'll see that you've matched both `98+66-979` as well as `9`

Answer (score 1):

`String.match` returns an array of matched items. In your case you have received two items `['98+66-97','9']`, but `alert` function outputs them as one string `'98+66-97,9'`.
 Instead of `match` function use `String.replace` function to remove(filter) all unallowable characters from input number:

```
var number = '98+66-97fffg9',
    res = number.replace(/[^0-9\+\-\(\)\s]+/g, "");

console.log(res);   // 98+66-979
```

Answer (score 1):

`stringvariable.match(/[0-9\+\-\(\)\s]+/g);` will give you output of matching strings from `stringvariable` excluding unmatching characters.

In your case your string is `98+66-97fffg9` so as per the regular expression it will eliminate "fffg" and will give you array of `["98+66-97","9"]`.
Its default behavior of match function.

You can simply do `res.join('')` to get the required output.
Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

As per documents from [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match), the return value is

> An Array containing the entire match result and any parentheses-captured matched results, or null if there were no matches.

S,your return value contains

```
["98+66-97", "9"]
```

So if you want to skip `parentheses-captured matched results`

just remove ***g*** flag from regular expression.

So,your expression should like this one

`number.match(/[0-9\+\-\(\)\s]+/);`  which gives result `["98+66-97"]`

Comment: thanks a lot for your help :) The solution of Darek is that  the 2 groups found.can be joined.